# ffmpeg output redirect to file is buffered and not after every line

Tags: ffmpeg, command-prompt

I'm trying to output the stderr output of ffmpeg to a file as an example...

`ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -vf scale='bitand(oh*dar,65534)':'min(720,ih)' -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -c:a aac -y sample1.mp4 2>output.log`

I notice that the output.log file is written to only in chunks and not every line. How do I get the ouput to the file every line-by-line so I can then process that file and get progress information in realtime? Currently it outputs first few lines and then waits and dumps everything only at the end.

Comment: *Currently it outputs first few lines and then waits and dumps everything only at the end.* --> Not my experience. Use `-progress` instead.

Comment: @Gyan Tried that too. No such luck. Tried with different source videos (of varying durations), effect is the same. The output.log file is created and updated for initial few seconds and thereafter all output is buffered and dumped at the end when everything finishes.

Comment: `-progress` writes to a specifed file, by default, every 0.5 seconds. It doesn't affect the stderr output.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan. Got it. My Notepad++ wasn't refreshing the file every time I looked at it (which it normally does). I then closed and file and reopened it and it was having the updates every time I did it.

Comment: To adjust the output interval of `-progress`, use `-stats_period` .